# Change scrollbar speed (Mouse wheel acceleration)

Tags: mouse, macos

I just upgraded to El Capitan, and was wondering how do I make the scrollbar scroll more lines and always scroll that many lines with each tick of the mouse wheel? Right now, the scrollbar goes up/down depending on how fast you move the scroll wheel on the mouse.

Before I upgraded, USB Overdrive managed to fix this issue but now it seems like that app is not doing anything. I change the wheel up/down speed to 20 lines and it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded USB Overdrive v3.1 this morning w/ El Capitan and it's working just fine. It was a fresh install of USB Overdrive as I did not have it on Yosemite. Maybe uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for some answers for a different problem and came across a little app called SmoothScroll, which allows you to change the amount of the scroll step (pixel numeric value), the animation time (millisecond numeric value), and the acceleration specs. While it doesn't solve my problem and you already got an answer to yours, I thought that I'd still share, in case that someone else viewing this thread might benefit from the tip.